# why my live server is not working on google chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-developers-console, liveserver, brave

When i click on "live sever" from visual studio it opens Google Chrome but my css is not working. When i copy the link on Brave it works...

[This is the CSS]

```
* {
  color: green;
}

#parrafo {
  color: blue;
}

p {
  color: red
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

[Here is how the html shows in Chrome. And the devs console. It's all in green!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puRFg.png)

[Brave. There is not green at all and i think this is the right html.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sdei.png)

Even the console styles is different...
"inherited from p" says in chrome.

Why is not working correctly? I'm new at this.

i'd like to know if the live server is not working or if my css styles sheet is wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question and use the snippet tool `<>` and paste your html and css there.  You cant expect people to click on links look at images and type in what you have.

Comment: Hi, adding to @RohitGupta comment, read this: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)

Comment: You are missing a semicolon in `p`

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but I notice that you are using the font tag which is now deprecated - consider using CSS. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code shown is that the text is within a font HTML element.

You have set everything to have color green except for p elements.

So the font element is correctly picking up the green setting.

Here's a simplified example:

```css
* {
  color: green;
}

p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <font>this is within a font element</font>
</p>
```

Nowadays the font tag is deprecated (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)) but if you for some reason need to keep it then you want in this case for the font element to inherit the p color.

However, you might like to take this opportunity to change the font element to something else (e.g. span, it depends on your use case) and make p span inherit the p color.